# Using "OR" and "AND" to validate an Outlook form

Tags: vba, forms, outlook

I am trying to validate an outlook form using an an `OR` statement.
When I validate without `OR`, the formula below works. The form is not sent and the appropriate error message appears.

```
([Number] <>"1" )
```

But when I try to make it a compound validation by using "OR", the validation does not work.

```
([Number] <>"1" ) OR ([Number] <>"2" )
```

The form is sent and the appropriate even when Number = 1 and the validation message is not displayed.

I have tried to use the symbols `||` instead of `OR`, but it doesn't work at all. I get an Outlook generated error message that has nothing to do with the issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the form sent if `Number` is not 1 or 2 then you should use `AND` not `OR`.

If you use `OR`and `Number` is 1 this expression will evaluate to `TRUE`.

```
([Number] <>"1") OR ([Number] <>"2")
```

Comment: Thank you @Joel CoeHoorn
I misunderstood what the symbol "<>" means. Please let me clarify. I actually want an error message to be displayed if a User Chooses a Certain Product Type

So if a user chooses Product "B" , then an error message is displayed and the form is not sent.

I tried : [Product] ="B"
Where the [Product] field is text

But no error error message is displayed when a user selects Product B. Which is why I ended up trying "<>"

Please see updated image

So why doesn't this syntax work:  [Product] ="B"

Answer (score 0):

Say your value is `1`. When you check it with `(Number <> "1") OR (Number <> "2")`, it is `false` for the first part and `true` for the second part. `false OR true` is `true`. The same applies for the value `2`: (`true OR false`) is still `true`.  For that matter, it applies for the value `3` (`true OR true`) and anything else you might have.

In other words, the expression `(Number <> "1") OR (Number <> "2")` is logically **always true**.

You probably want an `AND` here:

```
(Number <> "1") AND (Number <> "2")
```

Now for the same 1,2,3 test we get `false AND true`, which is `false`, `true AND false`, which is `false`, and `true AND true`, which is `true`.

---

Finally, it seems you are treating numbers are strings. Is that really what you have? VBA allows this, and often it is correct because you're actually pulling a string from the document. But if you actually have a numeric value here, be careful. Because of cultural/localization/internationalization concerns, converting back and forth between numbers and strings is surprising complicated and expensive, meaning it can slow down your program and introduce unexpected bugs. It's something to avoid whenever possible.